# Convertir texto desde C y Sqlite3 (unsigned char*) hacia C++ y string

Tags: sqlite

Utilizar bases de datos Sqlite3 para proyectos pequeños es sumamente util.

Para situaciones sencillas donde se tienen pocos registros (algunos cientos), la manipulacion de bases de datos Sqlite3 con lenguajes de alto nivel como Python (o incluso VBA en excel) resulta suficiente (por ejemplo tiempos de ejecución razonables de menos de 1 minuto).

Pero en situaciones complejas donde se tienen un poco más registros (entre miles y millones), es necesario utilizar lenguajes de menor nivel como C o C++.

En el caso de utilizar el sistema operativo Windows, el manejo de campos de tipo texto presenta una dificultad particular: el tipo de dato nativo.

En particular, Sqlite3 utiliza "unsigned char*" (funcion "sqlite3_column_text") pero el procesamiento posterior se realiza con funciones de texto comunes que utilizan otro tipo de datos: "char *".

Convertir textos entre estos tipos no es sencillo. Así, los ejemplos encontrados funcionan bien si se utiliza "c" pero fallan si se utiliza "c++".

el problema es: ¿como se puede convertir textos recibidos por la funcion "sqlite3_column_text" de "unsigned char*", hacia textos comunes de "char*"?

He probado diversos metodos pero no me han funcionado.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
En esta version he utilizado el concepto de "char" y "unsigned char", junto con las "uniones" de "c", para proponer una solución.

Para ello, se crea una union que contiene ambos tipos de datos, se crea una variable de este tipo de datos unión, se reciben los datos como "unsigned char*", luego se construye una nueva cadena de texto "string" y se convierte a "char *".

```
    //funciones de cadena
    #include <string.h>
    
    ...
    //define union
    union PUNTEROTEXTO{
        const char *ptr_cc;
        unsigned const char *ptr_ucc;
    } mPT;
    ...
    
    //crea variables
    const char* mitexto;
    PUNTEROTEXTO xpt; //conversion de texto (de "unsigned" char a "signed" char)
    
    //recibe datos
    xpt.ptr_ucc=sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0); //direcciona mismo espacio de memoria
    //convierte datos
    mitexto = string(xpt.ptr_cc).c_str();//crea nuevo objeto cadena y devuelve direccion
    
    ...
```

He notado que funciona en forma aleatoria.
Es posible que el problema se deba a la ubicación del string en memoria. Al utilizarlo dentro de un bloque de función se almacena en el stack y cuando se sale de la función la memoria se libera, y luego en forma posterior ya no contiene datos validos.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Esta versión es más complicada pero al momento me ha dado resultado.
Utiliza una función donde se reserva memoria en el heap con malloc en una variable local, luego transfiere los caracteres a dicha variable local, y finalmente asigna el puntero de salida hacia la variable local, que ya se encuentra ubicada en el heap.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

#include <time.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 


...

//funcion auxiliar
//recibe puntero texto sqlite unsigned const char
//aloja memoria en destino, convierte a char * y copia de origen a destino
void conv_ucc2cc(unsigned const char *&ptr_ucc_origen, const char *&ptr_cc_destino){
    PUNTEROTEXTO ptt;
    char *cc_destino;
    //almacena "unsigned char*"" en union con "signed char*""
    ptt.ptr_ucc = ptr_ucc_origen;
    //reserva memoria interna en el heap (global-malloc)
    cc_destino = (char*) malloc(strlen(ptt.ptr_cc) + 1);
    //copia memoria interna
    strcpy( cc_destino, ptt.ptr_cc );
    //reasigna puntero destino a memoria interna
    ptr_cc_destino = cc_destino;
}

union PUNTEROTEXTO{
    const char *ptr_cc;
    unsigned const char *ptr_ucc;
} mPT;

...
//crea las variables
PUNTEROTEXTO xpt; //conversion de texto (de "unsigned" char a "signed" char)
const char* mitexto;

...
/* asigna propiedades de objeto*/
xpt.ptr_ucc=sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);//direcciona mismo espacio de memoria
conv_ucc2cc(xpt.ptr_ucc, mitexto);
...
```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

El contexto es un sistema operativo Windows, el proyecto "w64devkit" y su variante "x86_64-w64-mingw32", los compiladores "gcc.exe" y "g++.exe", la version "sqlite-amalgamation-3420000" de Sqlite3, y el editor de codigo VS Code.

Lo que quisiera saber es si esta solución cumple con la lógica de Sqlite y de "c++", o si existe otra forma de hacerlo.